# trying to remove first and last square brackets from json injecting data into configmap using helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, configmap

I have data in a JSON file and am adding each line as key value into a ConfigMap using Helm, but i need to remove first and last curly brackets.

Below is the JSON file content:

```
{
    "type": "PurposeResourcesDefinition",
    "version": "1.0",
    "purposeId": "p#####",
    "description": "Artifactory container registry",
    "resources": [{
        "type": "artifactory.containerregistry",
        "name": "<repository name prefixed with the purpose>"
    ]
}
```

I am using the below Helm syntax:

```yaml
data:
  {{ range .Files.Lines "foo/app.json" }}
  {{ . }}{{ end }}
```

How can I remove the surrounding curly brackets using Helm templating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that `{` and `}` will be on lines by themselves, you can just skip them.  This isn't especially robust, but it will work for the example you show.

```yaml
data:
{{- range .Files.Lines "foo/app.json" }}
{{- if and (ne . "{") (ne . "}") }}
  {{ . }}
{{- end }}
```

At a higher level, it looks like you're trying to read in a JSON file and then write these values out as the contents of a ConfigMap.  Stripping the leading and trailing braces will work because of the syntactic similarities between YAML and JSON, but it might be better to actively convert from one format to the other.  Helm has [several undocumented conversion functions](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/pkg/engine/funcs.go#L50) including `fromJson` and `toYaml`.  So you can also write this as:

```yaml
data: {{- .Files.Get "foo/app.json" | fromJson | toYaml | nindent 2 }}
```

Comment: thanks , i tried second one as below 
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
name: {{ .Release.Name }}
data: {{- .Files.Get "files/dev/application_env_variables.json" | fromJson | toYaml | nindent 2 }}

but when run helm command.  its giving output as below

# Source: pipeline-be-test-api/templates/configmap_dev.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
name: RELEASE-NAME
data:
  Error: unexpected end of JSON input...

any idea what i am missing here

Comment: also this is my json file end part


  "spring.jpa.show-sql" : "\"true\"",
  "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql" : "\"true\"",
  "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" : "20",
  "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts" : "\"true\"",
  "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates" : "\"true\"",
  "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics" : "\"true\"",
  "logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL" : "TRACE",
  "logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder" : "TRACE"


}

Comment: Is the file actual correct well-formed JSON?  (I corrected a couple of things that looked like errors in the original question, but if it's not valid JSON, you'll get an error like that.)

Comment: also one more thing.  i donot want to hard code file path as i need to manage for multiple env.  
{{- .Files.Get "files/Dev/application_env_variables.json" | fromJson | toYaml | nindent 2 }}

i have folder structure for env like files/Dev, files/Tst ..etc.   i tried as below but did not work.. any suggestion
{{- .Files.Get(printf "files/%s/*".Values.environment) | fromJson | toYaml | nindent 2 }}

Thanks you for support